# How does material design handles 3D object?

Tags: logo, 3d, critique, google-material-design, depth

I am making a logo for my site. The site generator, [Material for MkDocs](https://squidfunk.github.io/mkdocs-material/), uses [Material Design v1](https://m1.material.io/), so I want to use this design for consistency.

The idea of the logo is a cube, representing objects (think of object icon in object-oriented programing). If it can contain a sphere inside then it even illustrates the idea better. Here is my try:

[image]

To see if it good or not, I try setting up a [social cards](https://squidfunk.github.io/mkdocs-material/setup/setting-up-social-cards/). Although the colors are compliment with each other, I feel that the logo still isn't fitted.

[image]

<sub>[SVG file](https://svgshare.com/i/sqS.svg)</sub>

<sub>I hope that you can help me find better adjectives.</sub>

Reading the documentation I think that while material design emphasizes on depth, the depth isn't really designed for a true full dimension: you don't really have more than 3 layers stacking on each other. So if material design is not a good choice for the logo, I wonder what style can go along with it?

<sub>Follow up: [Is it fine to design logo without any consideration with the design of UI?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/161010/26474)</sub>

Comment: Material Design is for creating user interfaces, not designing logos. Its concept of dimension is more of stacked paper sheets, not fully 3D objects.

Comment: I see. So what logo styles I should follow, which will go well with Material Design?

Comment: You can use any kind or style of logo you want.  Material design really has nothing to do with logos, or how logos should be designed.

Comment: Consider trying more flat colors (less shading). It also doesn't really have wireframe-looking things so maybe increase the width of the cube lines. Consider using the material design palette (or something that approximates it). I also believe material design would recommend white text on this sort of teal background

Comment: The sheer nature of 3D means it is in direct opposition to "Material Design" concepts. --- But there is no rule that one *must* use the "Material Design" concepts for any logotype.

Comment: Is there any example for a logo not in material design being used in material design without any problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said in the comments.

Material design https://m3.material.io/ is a system to create User Interfaces, not Graphic Identity.

It has some guidelines that can be considered 3 dimensional, but only for interaction, a button is considered "pushable" in real life, so, the proposal there is to have it simulated using a shadow.

---

Your question does not really relate to that specific design system. Your question is more about some styles of making a Logo. But in short a logo should "never" be designed as a 3D shape that depends on gradients to work.

Take a look at the concept of icon.  https://www.google.com/search?q=icons You can see icons for many objects that obviously are 3D in real life, but they are "abstracted" to work as a 2D image, most of them only 1 color.

A good logo can work even in only 1 color, black, or a negative version in white with a dark background. So you need to think a logo as it should be. a clear 2D shape or image.

---

Just for fun. (Do not consider this as a logo) Here is a redrawing of your image in a flat style to illustrate what I mean regarding a 1 color logo.

[image]

Of course you can play with 2 colors or more, but the image do not depends on the gradient to work.

Comment: That's cool. Thanks. Why shouldn't that be used as a logo?