# Is it fine to design logo without any consideration with the design of UI?

Tags: logo, interface-design

The comments of [How does material design handles 3D object?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/160999/26474) have a consensus that one can design a logo in any style I want, regardless of the design of the UI, and the two will still play along with each other. Is that correct?

Comment: Logos should be designed so that they are not linked to any medium, mainly because you do not today know where you will need to use the logo.

Comment: I see. Do you have any good resource about designing logo that you can recommend?

Comment: You're now essentially asking "how to design a logo" which is a very broad question... Start here https://bookauthority.org/books/best-logo-design-books

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If one thinks about the **usage** of any logo, it somewhat reframes the mindset around this question.

A logo *can* be used for...

- Stationary
- Web Site
- Signage
- Promotional items (pens, cups, etc)
- Vehicle wraps
- Mobile app
- Packaging
- And more

Just look around you now as you read this... see how many items you can spot that contain a logo of some sort. Which ones work well, which ones may not.

So, if one designs a logo based on one of the above, who is to say it will work as well for *any* of the other items? A logo *specifically* designed to work in a web-based UI *may* reflect miserably on packaging, or promotional items. And conversely, if one *specifically* designs a logo to work well on a (leave-behind) cup or pen... it may not work well for building signage.

The brand logo is the *most important* image any business will ever have. A logo will be the most used image, should be the most recognized, and the most consistent for any venture. To this end, the logo needs to have the best possible appearance and convey a *specific* "mood" or "mindset" of any company. By trying to "design to a UI" the creative ideation is then limited. When designing a logo, it's best to be as creatively free as possible to conjure up *whatever* one can to meet the goals of the brand.

Logos should be designed as *logos*. One should not directly consider practical usage (beyond color applications and reproduction requirements).

A well designed logo will work equally well at various sizes for *all* of the above list items.

---

So, with the above in mind... **Yes**. it is fine to design a logo *without* considering a web UI. It is **preferable** to *not* design a logo to match a UI. If anything, a UI should *possibly* be designed to match an already defined logo.

Comment: also in Trade show booths, business card (just try doing anything in Japan without one), illuminated sign on side of a office building, etched on glass, TV/Video commercial, newsprint, clothing, sports arena, on PCB silkscreen...